# nested "Any" in is not working in dynamic linq

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

We offer our users the ability to build their own queries on the data. To make this work we use the Dynamic LINQ library. 
This construct is giving us problems: We have a collection of persons which we query as follows:

```
( DossierItems.Any( DossierFiles.Any())) && ( FirstName.Contains( \"h\" ) )
```

This results in the error stating that:

> No property or field 'FirstName' exists in type 'DossierItem'

Which is entirely correct: FirstName is  a property of person. The closing parenthesis after the second “any” is somehow missed.

```
( FirstName.Contains( \"h\" ) ) && ( DossierItems.Any( DossierFiles.Any() ) )
```

The statement above works just fine, but we can’t control the order in which the predicates are entered.

Is there a way in which to modify the nested Any parts so the play nice with any following predicates?

This is the stack trace produced by Dynamic Linq when parsing the dynamic linq string:

```
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseMemberAccess(Type type, Expression instance)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseIdentifier()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimaryStart()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimary()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseUnary()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseMultiplicative()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseAdditive()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseComparison()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalAnd()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalOr()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseExpression()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseParenExpression()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimaryStart()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimary()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseUnary()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseMultiplicative()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseAdditive()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseComparison()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalAnd()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalOr()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseExpression()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.Parse(Type resultType)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(ParameterExpression[] parameters, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(Type itType, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.Where(IQueryable source, String predicate, Object[] values)
   at Repositories.Base.Repository`1.ApplyQuery(IQueryable`1 entities, Guid queryId)
   at Search.SearchQueryResult.RunQuery[T](IQueryable`1 entities, IRepository`1 repository)
```

**Code sample for repro**

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
```

namespace ClassLibrary1
   {

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // arrange
        var allAs = new List<A>();

        // act
        // pass
        var actual = allAs.Where("(Name = \"\")&&(Bs.Any(Cs.Any()))");

        // fail
        var actual = allAs.Where("(Bs.Any(Cs.Any()))&&(Name = \"\")");        
    }
}

public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<B> Bs
    {
        get { return bs; }
        set { bs = value; }
    }
    private IList<B> bs = new List<B>(0);
}

public class B
{
    public A A { get; set; }
    public IList<C> Cs
    {
        get { return cs; }
        set { cs = value; }
    }
    private IList<C> cs = new List<C>(0);
}

public class C
{
    public B B { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Just to be sure, which Dynamic Linq Library are you using?

Comment: And can you show us the dynamic linq statement before it is executed and if you execute this against a database the SQL as well?

Comment: @stefan I'm using System.Linq.Dynamic 1.0.4 by kahanu version

Comment: @Stefan: There is no SQL executed. It explodes with a System.Linq.Dynamic.ParesException. I do have a stack trace longer than my leg if you are interested?

Comment: Yes, that is helpful. And if you like, some more of the way you're building up the query.

Comment: Your parantheses don't seem to be properly closed in either example (5 open, 4 closed).

Comment: @RaduB sorry about that, fixed that in the question text. All parenthesis were present in the code.

Comment: @Stefan: I have added the stacktrace to the question

Comment: Hmm, stack trace doesn't shed much light on it. Can you post a full example string? And the way the string is constructed? Maybe there is a possibility to alter the order in some way.

Comment: @Stefan: That is part of the problem. The users can construct any number of predicates using our query builder and string them together using "AND" and "OR"'s as they see fit. I now do the combinations as a concatenation of string elements in one huge dynamic linq string. If there is no dynamic linq library who handles this correctly, I will have resort to combining the individual predicates with Unions and Intersects. That will take some doing, but it gives an escape...

Comment: @Stefan: I added a complete code sample that strips the problem to the bare bones. but produces the same error

Comment: Do you have any update? I'm actually facing the exact same problem with nested .Any using System.Linq.Dynamic 1.0.4 by kahanu.

Answer (score 1):

If it's of any help to anyone, I figured out the cause. It is an issue in the original source and i have just done a pull request on Github with a fix for it.

https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/pull/68

This issue will occur with any nested linq method call. Solved by replacing a variable in their parser with a Stack to get the right Type to be popped when stepping out of a method call.

Comment: Awesome! Have moved on since posting this question. I hope your fix makes it into the code base.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work with the original source code which can be downloaded here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/bb894665.aspx

Just use the CSharpSamples\LinqSamples\DynamicQuery\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs class instead of the System.Linq.Dynamic NuGet package.

Comment: Thanks, I have moved on to different things in the mean time, so it will be a while before i can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Already works fine in my branch from this library : [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/1.0.6.10)